# Different results from wilcoxsign_test - which test to use?

Tags: r, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I am running a wilcoxsign_test from the coin-package and I get different results depending on whether I split my data or not.

My data is a data.frame with 3 columns: "Proband", "Treatment", "Mdev".
Treatment is either "user" or "drive" and Mdev is the value that the probands reached in either treatment. So the data is in long form.

```
Proband | Treatment | Mdev
1         user        0.5
1         drive       0.3
2         user        0.6
2         drive       0.4
...
```

I don't know if I didn't understand the function correctly, or what the issue is. My feeling tells me, that the first one is correct, because it knows which Probands belong together?

```
wilcoxsign_test(Mdev ~ Treatment | Proband, df)
#Z = -2.0333, p-value = 0.04202

baseData <- subset(df,Treatment=="user")
treatData <- subset(df,Treatment=="drive")
wilcoxsign_test(baseData$Mdev ~ treatData$Mdev)
#Z = -3.5974, p-value = 0.0003214

wilcox.test(baseData$Mdev, treatData$Mdev, paired=T)
#V = 219, p-value = 6.676e-05
```

This is my data:

```
    structure(list(Proband = structure(c(8L, 12L, 11L, 18L, 1L, 7L, 
5L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 9L, 21L, 7L, 20L, 6L, 16L, 16L, 14L, 4L, 17L, 
13L, 14L, 1L, 9L, 4L, 8L, 15L, 10L, 2L, 20L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 17L, 
10L, 19L, 15L, 18L, 3L, 3L, 21L, 19L), .Label = c("4", "5", "9", 
"10", "11", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "22", "25", 
"26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32"), class = "factor"), 
    Treatment = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("drive", "user"), class = "factor"), 
    Mdev = c(0.77774, 0.70899, 0.67463, 0.63176, 0.58867, 0.57463, 
    0.57292, 0.57211, 0.56916, 0.56678, 0.56117, 0.55627, 0.53442, 
    0.53248, 0.53046, 0.51774, 0.48093, 0.47656, 0.47519, 0.47036, 
    0.46646, 0.46587, 0.4637, 0.44291, 0.44087, 0.42865, 0.42602, 
    0.40904, 0.40524, 0.40499, 0.39791, 0.35671, 0.3315, 0.32965, 
    0.31296, 0.29784, 0.29521, 0.28068, 0.27107, 0.22477, 0.21352, 
    0.20689)), row.names = c(NA, -42L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

(Crosspost from stackoverflow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you sort your data first, you will get commensurate results from all three function calls.

```
df=    structure(list(Proband = structure(c(8L, 12L, 11L, 18L, 1L, 7L, 
5L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 9L, 21L, 7L, 20L, 6L, 16L, 16L, 14L, 4L, 17L, 
13L, 14L, 1L, 9L, 4L, 8L, 15L, 10L, 2L, 20L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 17L, 
10L, 19L, 15L, 18L, 3L, 3L, 21L, 19L), .Label = c("4", "5", "9", 
"10", "11", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "22", "25", 
"26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32"), class = "factor"), 
    Treatment = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("drive", "user"), class = "factor"), 
    Mdev = c(0.77774, 0.70899, 0.67463, 0.63176, 0.58867, 0.57463, 
    0.57292, 0.57211, 0.56916, 0.56678, 0.56117, 0.55627, 0.53442, 
    0.53248, 0.53046, 0.51774, 0.48093, 0.47656, 0.47519, 0.47036, 
    0.46646, 0.46587, 0.4637, 0.44291, 0.44087, 0.42865, 0.42602, 
    0.40904, 0.40524, 0.40499, 0.39791, 0.35671, 0.3315, 0.32965, 
    0.31296, 0.29784, 0.29521, 0.28068, 0.27107, 0.22477, 0.21352, 
    0.20689)), row.names = c(NA, -42L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

library(coin)

Sorted = df[order(as.numeric(df$Proband), as.numeric(df$Treatment)),] 

baseData <- subset(Sorted,Treatment=="user")
treatData <- subset(Sorted,Treatment=="drive")

hist(baseData$Mdev - treatData$Mdev, col="darkgray")

wilcoxsign_test(Mdev ~ Treatment | Proband, df)

   ### data:  y by x (pos, neg) 
   ### stratified by block
   ### Z = -2.0333, p-value = 0.04202
   ### alternative hypothesis: true mu is not equal to 0

wilcoxsign_test(baseData$Mdev ~ treatData$Mdev)

   ### data:  y by x (pos, neg) 
   ###   stratified by block
   ### Z = 2.0333, p-value = 0.04202
   ### alternative hypothesis: true mu is not equal to 0

wilcox.test(baseData$Mdev, treatData$Mdev, paired=T)

   ### data:  baseData$Mdev and treatData$Mdev
   ### V = 174, p-value = 0.04208
   ### alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```